# Refresh Case via Visualflow running in Custom Console Component

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, service-cloud-console

I have a VisualFlow related to a case that runs via a Visualforce page loaded in the Sidebar Custom Console Component.  The case is not in Edit mode, but the Flow does make updates to the  case record.
When the flow ends, I need to get the case record to refresh. They are in the same tab in the Service Console. Also, to make it a bit more difficult, I also have many use cases where this refresh also needs to start a secondary flow.
Basically, I need the flow finish to refresh the tab it is running in, update the case record and reload the VF page that houses the original flow.  Has anyone implemented something like this, and if so, can you share any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the Service Cloud Console, I think it's the same root cause as [this bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2GXAA0) posted to the Known Issues site.